# rsync: copy updated/new files to DIFFERENT directory

Tags: rsync

I'd like to do a backup with the following structure

```
/source # the source directory which should be backed up

/backup/initial/... # the first initial copy/backup of the source
/backup/snapshots/YYYYmmDDHHmmss/... # (1)
/backup/changed/YYYYmmDDHHmmss/... # (2)
```

(1) is the "default" behavior of rsync I guess. Make a snapshot with hard links back to the initial backup. I would do this via `rsync -avuP --link-dest=$initial_backup $directory_to_backup $destination`

(2) I get the rsync outputs for this via
`rsync -riv --ignore-existing "$directory_to_backup"/ "$last_backup"/`
and
`rsync -riv --existing "$directory_to_backup"/ "$last_backup"/`

but now I would like to hard link the output of these two scripts into the `changed` directory.

My goal is to have both, full snapshots of the directory I'd like to backup but also a `changed` directory containing only new and modified files. Everything with hard links to avoid taking too much space.

Comment: Right after an rsync command to create a snapshot, any regular file in the snapshot with hardlink count = 1 will be new.  I don't believe rsync preserves harlinks on the source (though you should double check).  It might be possible to use this to build up the "changed" directory immediately after the rsync.

Comment: I thought about something like using the `n` flag and generate a list of new/updated files and afterwards use that list to hard link them to the `changed` directory - but I don't know how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you just need to change the order a little. You can use `--compare-dest` to create the directory of new and changed files, then use two `--link-dest` args to link back this changed directory, and the previous snapshot. Here's an example test script:

```bash
cd /tmp/
rm -fr src backup
mkdir -p src/a/b backup
date >src/a/b/unchanged
date >src/a/b/c
rsync -a src/ backup/i
rsync -a --link-dest=../i/ src/ backup/s1
sleep 1
date >src/a/b/c
date >src/a/b/c2
rsync -av --compare-dest=../s1 src/ backup/ch
rsync -av --link-dest=../s1 --link-dest=../ch src/ backup/s2
ls -li backup/*/*/*/*
```

which gave me this output:

```
919 -rw-r--r-- 2  backup/i/a/b/c
920 -rw-r--r-- 3  backup/i/a/b/unchanged
919 -rw-r--r-- 2  backup/s1/a/b/c
920 -rw-r--r-- 3  backup/s1/a/b/unchanged
472 -rw-r--r-- 2  backup/ch/a/b/c
473 -rw-r--r-- 2  backup/ch/a/b/c2
472 -rw-r--r-- 2  backup/s2/a/b/c
473 -rw-r--r-- 2  backup/s2/a/b/c2
920 -rw-r--r-- 3  backup/s2/a/b/unchanged
```

Here, directory `i` is the initial backup, `s1` snapshot1, `s2` snapshot2, and `ch` the changes corresponding to snapshot2. The first column is the inode number, and the 3rd is the hard link count. It shows that changed file `c` is hard-linked to `ch`, new file `c2` is hard-linked to `ch`, and the unchanged file is hard-linked to `s1` and `i`.

Comment: that's it, thank you VERY much!